# Force users to get the latest app version

Tags: ios, iphone

I've searched here but couldn't find the right answer. Is there any way that Apple will approve an app that perform a check at start if the user have the latest version, if not, it will show an alert with a demand to update to latest version else the user will not be able to continue?

Comment: It seems like some financial institutions (banks, stock trading services, etc.) would have this requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of games (for example, Clash of Clans) have such a behavior. There should not be troubles with it.

There is nothing about such a rejection in Apple's Appstore guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can ask the user to update the application. Apple won't reject your application.

You can show an alert message that an update is available or you can directly open the app store with showing your updated app (it is easier for the user to update quickly).

You may either use your own site web-service or itunes webservice to check whether an update for the app is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually check if a user is using the latest version by hosting a text file online. Then you could check if the version in the text file is the same as the app version