# How to force users to update app?

Tags: java, android, ios, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have a condition where the internal DB will be changed and after the migration the old app will no longer work. Is there a way that google play or apple app store provides any flag which does this job?

Also I don't have any version check in my current app (which is already with customers) so cannot display any message in the current app to download new app and ask them to update or quit the app.

I am using Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 to create IOS & Android apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not force users to update the application but you can send them push notification for updating the application if they want to and you have implemented into current version.

But when you release the update they are able to get notify by app store and if they want they can install the update from there..

Comment: I would like to know about negative make for the answer so that i can learn what is the wrong

Comment: Do you have any source which I can refer that one cannot force users to update? Is there any other way possible from app stores itself?

Comment: For that need to implement Push notification service for that need to submit new .ipa to appstore

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221436/can-i-force-an-iphone-user-to-upgrade-an-application
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824179/force-users-to-get-the-latest-app-version

read here for better understanding..

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot force users to update the app using Google play or AppStore build-in feature, you can use third party librairies that do exactly what you want. [appgrades.io](https://appgrades.io) allows you to block any version of your app by displaying a view or popup (that you can customise on appgrades [Dashboard](https://dash.appgrades.io)) with a custom message to ask your users to update the app. You can even add an update button that sends the users to the appstore/Google play where they can update the app. No code needed. Just integrate the SDK in your app and block any version anytime.

The other solution would be coding what appgrades does by checking with your api the latest available version and block the app with a view when you are running a lower version.